# A non well formed numeric value encountered using maths functions in cakephp3

Tags: php

I have seen all past examples of this error but the examples are for a date function. My problem is different because  I am using maths function and it throws me this error:

> A non well formed numeric value encountered on line 257

Below is my code snippet - I am doing my code on cakephp3.x

```
foreach($query as $row)
{
    $lat=$row->lat.'<br>';
    $lng=$row->lng.'<br>';
    $lat1=$formlatitude;
    $lon1=$formlongitude;
    $lat2=$lat;
    $lon2=$lng;

    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);
    $miles=$miles * 1.609344;
    //echo $miles;
    //Although distance is calculated in kms only
    if($miles<10)
    {
        echo $miles;
    }

}
```

I have values of variables like

`$lat1=23.02650164397716`

And so on - they are decimals. The error occurs on this line:

```
$dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
```

Comment: Learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide your **error message** ! That will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: It throws me this error dude: A non well formed numeric value encountered on line 257 Which is $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta)); this line

Comment: Try : `$lat1=(float)$formlatitude;`
What is your international language/numbers settings ?

Comment: if `$lat2=$lat` then it contains junk, since `$lat=$row->lat.'<br>';` which will cause `deg2rad($lat2)` to barf. Why are you adding HTML to what should be numeric values? It'll probably work if you use `$lat2=$row->lat` instead.

Comment: Cool! The problem was i was adding <br> tag and later on it was going on this maths function code. I was debugging by adding <br> tags so I forgot to remove that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting

```
$lat=$row->lat.'<br>';
```

followed by:

```
$lat2=$lat;
```

So now regardless of what `$lat1` contains, `$lat2` is a string with HTML in it, not a number.

Next up, you  try to use `$lat2` as a number in:

```
deg2rad($lat2)
```

It'll probably work if you use:

```
$lat2=$row->lat;
```

instead.

I think the problem you're facing could be better addressed by making sure you know what's in each variable. Using a name like `lat` to refer to a string in one place and a number in another is likely to cause issues as time goes on.

Comment: Cool! The problem was i was adding <br> tag and later on it was going on this maths function code. I was debugging by adding <br> tags so I forgot to remove that. Thanks!